# PHP mailer Custom acknowledgement page?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm not a PHP guy so I googled and found some simple code for a contact form via kirupa.com Everything works great, however I'd love to **serve up a custom thank you / acknowledgement page** instead users getting a simple echo text *"Data has been submitted to your@email.com!"* on a white blank page.

My contact form:
http://leongaban.com/contact.html

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $to = "your@email.com";
   $subject = "Form My website";
   $name_field = $_POST['name'];
   $email_field = $_POST['email'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];

   $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";

   echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
    mail($to, $subject, $body);
    } else {
    echo "error! :'(";
    }
?>
```

**How should I edit this code to serve the users a thankyou.html page after they send an email?**

Comment: Don't tag with PHPMailer when you're not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use header function http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $to = "your@email.com";
   $subject = "Form My website";
   $name_field = $_POST['name'];
   $email_field = $_POST['email'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];

    $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";
    mail($to, $subject, $body);
    header('Location:  thankyou.html');

    } 
else {
    echo "error! :'(";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to find a PHP Tuts+ class

Answer (score 3):

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $to = "your@email.com";
        $subject = "Form My website";
        $name_field = $_POST['name'];
        $email_field = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";


        if(mail($to, $subject, $body))
        {
            header("Location: http://yourdomain/thankyoupage.php");
        }
        else
        {
          echo "Error !";
        } 
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use header for redirecting to page:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
  header("Location: http://your/thankyou/page/url");
  exit;
}
else{
 ...
}
```

Did you mean something like this